# PHPMyAdmin login looks weird

Tags: php

I just installed PHPMyAdmin on a new machine, and unlike every other time, the login uses the "browser" login. In Safari, it says: To view this page, you must log in to this area on 102.54.***.2*8:80:

On all my other installs, it actually gives a real PhpMyadmin login page, that had PHPMyAdmins logo at the top. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you don't have access to the PHPMyAdmin files itself. Change the `index.php` file of PHPMyAdmin and check whether it runs. If not, check your Apache configurations.